# Python read shared Outlook inbox, find text in sub or body, if found, create new folder, or move to existing

Tags: python, outlook, move

I have a shared inbox that receives messages with `"ABC-*****"` in either the subject or body. Let's call that the classifier.

I want to write some python code that will scan this shared inbox and check for the classifier. If found, move the email to a folder within the shared address named the classifier, either creating a new folder if one does not exist or adding the message to an existing folder with that name.

I can use `Alteryx` to schedule this routine so just looking for the read, create/check for folder from subject/body, move code.

Answer (score 0):

*Work with pywin32, Python extensions for Microsoft Windows which Provides access to much of the [Win32 API](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)*

*To access the [shared Inbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder) try*

> ```
> import win32com.client
>
> Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
> olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
> shared_inbox = olNs.Folders["Shared_Inbox_Email@email"].Folders["Inbox"]
> ```
>
> ---

*then filter emails by subject line using [Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict)*

> ```
> Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" +
>           chr(34) + " Like 'subject line here'")
>
> Items = shared_inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
>
> for Item in Items:
>     Item.Display()
> ```
>
> ---

*Or move item to sub folder*

> ```
> sub_folder = shared_inbox.Folders["sub_folder_name"]
> for Item in Items:
>     Item.Move(sub_folder)
> ```
>
> ---